# Send Serial data and Ethernet data both over WiFi

Tags: embedded, serial, ethernet, wifi, rs232

we have to make an upgrade in the system which currently uses

1. serial communication using RS 232 which is wired(obviously).
2. send video data via ethernet.

So now we want to add send both the data over WiFi after taking input from ethernet and serial port and receive it over WiFi

I need some suggestions.

Comment: What's there to suggest? Switching the IP video to wireless should be trivial. Serial data I suppose you're looking for an encapsulation format, but you could just make a TCP connection?

Comment: Latency Requirement is 10MBps because of live video , They are 15m apart with only one access point , rest I just want to know a solution ( I am not proposing anything here)

Comment: @pjc50 I want have two connections , Serial and Ethernet , and I want to send both over WiFi

Comment: "10MBps" is not a 'latency' spec, it's a bit-rate spec. Latency is measured in units of time, not speed.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion is to first do a lot more of requirements engineering. Just a few things that I could spontaneously think of:

- How much data does your system need, per video source, and overall?
- How many endpoints are there?
- How far are they spread out?
- How many access points will you need?
- How many access points can you add at most, so that your overall
  capacity increases?
- What are your latency requirements?
- What are yourreliability requirements?
- How are these devices powered (i.e. when
  removing ethernet, aren't you also removing PoE and thus need to add
  back another power line?)?
- How OK is the scenario that a group of people watching youtube using an (ad-hoc) wifi on the same channel occupy > 50% of the available spectrum?
- How important is it that someone outside your facility can't figure out how much movement is in the video, based on observing the amount of data exchanged over the air?
- What problem are you solving here, and is what you're proposing actually a solution or does it just sound progressive?

Comment: I am asking for a solution if there is ,Latency is 10 MBps , all the other requirements are not really needed .this only end to end communication so only one access point I guess , No I only want to see what are the possible solutions , Powering it up is not  problem because it is alreadyon a mount with battery we can use the same.

Comment: "Latency is 10 Mbps" doesn't make sense at all, latency is time, and Mbps is a bit rate, and these two things have nothing to do with each other. I think you really don't yet fully understand what you're about to do, so my suggestion is: Don't do it until you've understood what *each* of my points actually means. At least for the first point, you need to have **two** different numbers, and you will have to check whether WiFi *guarantees* these in all situations where you want to deploy it. It really sounds like  it doesn't, to me, and you simply can't do what you plan-.